# Can we restrict downloading of source code from AWS Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

Is there any option in AWS to restrict developers to download source code from Cloud9 IDE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that could be possible, even if they (AWS) wanted to. If someone can see the code, they can copy the code - if only by copy and paste - so any attempt to prevent someone from downloading what they can already see with their own eyes, is going to fall short.

Comment: Thanks @Brennan for your response. Yes agree. As we are planning for Work From Home option in our organization going forward, I was just exploring if we can have restrictions in place and having Online IDE using personal laptops. Any other alternatives you want to suggest ?

Comment: As @E.J. Brennan said - it's virtually impossible. The best they could do would be to make it painful but not impossible. The only setup I've seen that solves this is using something like Citrix - but that's not very developer friendly IMHO.

Comment: IMO, copy/pasting code is different than downloading. Sometimes there are a lot of files in a project, which makes copy/pasting extremely painful. To be able to restrict download will be very effective. I have this exact pain-point, where i am seeing many freelancers downloading the whole project and just running away without completing the project.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot successfully integrate developers onto a team and restrict their access to source code. If you don't trust people to see or access the code, don't hire them would be my advice.